# Rails: RSpec - undefined method `cookie_jar' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rspec, capybara

Rails newbie. Trying to follow Michael Hartl's tutorial.

Stuck trying to add a helper method to simulate log in an RSpec test:

```
describe "when the a user has logged in and attempts to visit the page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
    before do 
      log_in user
    end
    it "should redirect the user to next page" do
      specify { response.should redirect_to loggedin_path }
    end
  end
```

In my spec/support/utilities.rb:

```
def log_in user
    visit root_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Log in"
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: log_in user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `cookie_jar' for nil:NilClass
```

What gives?

**Edit, full stack trace:**

```
Index page when the a user has logged in and attempts to visit the page should redirect the user to next page
     Failure/Error: log_in user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `cookie_jar' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:8:in `log_in'
     # ./spec/features/pages/index_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: link to tutorial? Point the line with error?

Comment: error is on 'cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token'. Tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: Is my edit the full stack trace? I'm sorry I am totally new to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Are you sure you want to visit the `root_path` and not the `signin_path`? Maybe you set yours up differently, but these were two distinct paths for me.

Comment: I'm not following the tutorial quite word for word, building my own application and i want my login on the root path. The route isn't the issue. It's the damn cookie jar or whatever that is. Stuck here.

Comment: What version of capybara is your Gemfile set to?

Comment: latest version, not specified a version

Comment: I seem to remember a similar error when I upgraded my Sample App to use Capybara 2.1.  Do you still get the error if you re-bundle to match the same Capybara version as the tutorial?

Comment: Do you have your current (failing) code in a Github repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec is very particular about the directory that you place your tests. If you put the test in the wrong directory, it won't automagically mix-in the various test helpers that setup different types of tests. It seems your setup is using `spec/features` which is not an approved [default directory](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/9e096df738695f03174bc80ca214a85de2b2bc8a/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb#L31) (`spec/requests`, `spec/integration`, or `spec/api`).

Based on the tutorial page, I'm not sure how they have the `spec_helper.rb` file setup. Though the examples so they are using `spec/requests` to hold the tests.

You can force RSpec to recognize another directory for request specs by using on of the following:

Manually add the proper module to the test file:

```
# spec/features/pages/index_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Visiting the index page" do

  include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup

  # Rest of your test code
  context "when the a user has logged in and attempts to visit the page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

    before do 
      log_in user
    end

    specify { response.should redirect_to loggedin_path }
  end

end
```

Include this in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file:

```
RSpec::configure do |c|
  c.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, example_group: {
    file_path: c.escaped_path(%w[spec (features)])
  }
end
```

Since this is a tutorial I'd recommend following the standard of including `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of the spec file and that your actual `spec/spec_helper.rb` file has `require 'rspec/rails'`

A minor note, you don't need to put a `specify` inside of an `it` block. They are aliases of each other, so just use one.

```
context "when the a user has logged in and attempts to visit the page" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

  before do 
    log_in user
  end

  # All of the following are the same

  it "redirects the user to next page" do
    response.should redirect_to loggedin_path
  end

  it { response.should redirect_to loggedin_path }

  specify "redirects the user to next page" do
    response.should redirect_to loggedin_path
  end

  specify { response.should redirect_to loggedin_path }
end
```

Note, according to the documentation for [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), you should be able to put your capybara tests into `spec/features`. To make this work, ensure you are loading `require 'capybara/rspec'` in your `spec_helper` or test spec file directly.

However, looking at the [source](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb), I didn't see where they are automatically including that directory. You can also try adding the tag `type: :feature` to the outer `describe` block in your test file. Though the more likely solution is to use `spec/requests`.

Comment: Thanks so much, been stuck on that for days.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have the "user" argument of the method enclosed in parenthesis?

```
def log_in(user)
    visit root_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Log in"
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Comment: Didn't think you needed to in Ruby? I'm a noob though so tell me if otherwise. Didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: I'm new too.. Searching around, I haven't seen this anywhere as a "valid" syntax to go with.

Comment: It's optional, both `def log_in user` and `def log_in(user)` are valid. However, typical convention is to use parens for the method definition.

Answer (score -1):

To have a mock cookie jar, you must have either `rack-test` or `rspec-rails` gem included in your `Gemfile`. I think maybe you have included just `rspec` and maybe missed out `rspec-rails`.

You also need to ensure you've configured the session store as follows:

`config.session_store = :cookie_store`

This must have been done in either `config/application.rb` or some file under `config/initializers`. If you have configured this in `config/environments/development.rb` or somewhere else, the Test environment will not be able to pick it up.

Comment: Thanks but that setting is already set in all environments and I am using the spec-rails gem already. Issue still remains.